# WSO2 data service, change schema where results are returned

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am working with WSO2 Data Service version 2.6. In this version the tool for contract firts service generation has been removed due to a bug, and it will be realease again in the next version.

We need to change the way the results are returned. We would like to define our own wsdl and generate an empty data service from it, where we finally set up each operation, data source and configure how the results are mapped to the wsdl schema types.

Is there any way of do this without data service contract first tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, there's no straightforward way to do this. You would have to carefully start from creating the data service yourself to make it generate a WSDL that will resemble the WSDL that you would need.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: thanks for your reply Anjara. We are thinking about deploying our specific wsdl in the ESB, and make a sequence where we call the data service and transform the response according to our specific schema.

Cheers, Fidel

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. That is what I thought but wanted to ask to fade out my doubts